# Time & memory complexity of a recursive method?

Tags: c#, recursion, big-o

I have a method that I can't understand the complexity of:

```
    static int op = 0;

    static int[] Solve(int[] arr, int n)
    {
        if (n == 0) return arr;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length - n - 1; i++)
        {
            op++;
            if (arr[i] == 0 && arr[i + n + 1] == 0)
            {
                arr[i] = n;
                arr[i + n + 1] = n;
                var arr3 = Solve(arr, n - 1);
                if (arr3.Length != 1)
                    return arr3;
                arr[i] = 0;
                arr[i + n + 1] = 0;
            }
        }
        return new int[1]; // return error
    }
```

The input & number of operations `op` are these (* is worst case):

```
N  | # operations
1  | 0*
2  | 3*
3  | 6
4  | 17
5  | 470*
6  | 2633*
7  | 128
8  | 336
9  | 571514*
10 | 3959493*
11 | 9665
12 | 2835
13 | 2070634950*
```

What is the O(n) on time and memory & why?

My thinking was that the time complexity is O(N!) since each call is made with f(n-1) * f(n-2)...f(n-n), but that's not what the research table shows — it's less. It isn't f(n!/2) either although the operations span only half the array.

The memory complexity would be O(N*N) since there's always an array of N in memory on N calls deep.

Comment: Yes, I think the time complexity is O(N!) since each call is made with f(n-1) * f(n-2)...f(n-n), but that's not what the research table shows — it's less. It isn't f(n!/2) either although the operations span only half the array.

Comment: Asking homework questions is not wrong per se, but you should say where it is you're stuck. Don't just ask people to do your work for you.

Comment: Step one in analysis of this kind of problem is, does the master theorem work? If yes, use it. If no, why not?

Comment: I added my theories to the question; this isn't homework but was for an interview - I'm interested if I was right or wrong.

Comment: For case 13 you are perilously close to the max int. Maybe use a long?